Retrieving data for lookup fields
I have two fields in my Intakes object called "Referred To" and "Client Name," both of which have lookup relationships with the Party/Account object.
To be able to get the data on these fields, I am attempting to create a lookup join between the Intakes and Account objects fusing the "Client Name = Party ID" and "Referred To = Party ID" conditions. While I successfully retrieved the results for the Client Name field, but I am encountering issues with retrieving data for the "Referred To" field.
Can someone please assist

can you maybe share some screenshots of your setup please - it is difficult to visualize just off of your description. Some input data and the expected output data will also be helpful.
